# Can I get the Facebook news feed with the hashtag to do anlytics in hadoop?

Tags: facebook, hadoop, mapreduce, flume, hadoop2

I want to get facebook feeds. I want to do some analytics on that in hadoop.

Is there any API available for facebook news feeds based on tags?

Answer (score 2):

No, Public Posts search is deprecated with v2.0 so you can´t search for hashtags either: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog